# How can I include custom jquery slider for related products Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, jquery, html, magento, slider

I am trying to build a **custom jquery slider** in the **Product page** meaning the **view.phtml** in Magento 1.7.0.2

The code below is working and It fetches me the **Related Products**

```
<?php $related_prods = $_product->getRelatedProductIds(); ?>
<?php foreach($related_prods as $related): ?>
    <?php $_rel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($related); ?>
    <?php echo $_rel->getName(); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $_rel->getImageUrl(); ?>"/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I would like to include this code with a **horizontal jquery slider** but I haven't found
something yet.

Does anyone has a **horizontal jquery slider** to include the php code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also follow this http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/33684/#t190949 to make related product working.

Comment: Thanks Ram I will try this approach

Answer (score 0):

There is free extension available in market. try this [extention page on magento connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/related-product-slider-5017.html)

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/related-product-slider-5017.html